# Unity Speech to text with Azure

Tags: android, azure, unity-game-engine

I want to implement Speech-to-text functionality using Azure on a Unity project that will be deployed to Android.
I have tried this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedcsharpdesktop
But Im not sure how Im supposed to implement this in my Unity project. Can anyone point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you are developing an Android App using Unity. So considering to the compatibility of client library for Android, I suggested that the best way is follow the other [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest) for REST API in C# to implement your needs in your Unity project, and first you need to implement a feature to record a speech audio file, then pass it as the request body of REST API.

For real-time streaming, please refer to [Speech Websocket Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol).

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I believe real-time streaming is not an option for the REST API right?

Comment: @199user911 Sure. But its [websocket API supports intermediate results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home#speech-to-text-speech-recognition). Please refer to the document about [Speech Websocket Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol) to implement your needs for real-time streaming.